# Jquery dataTable search draw toggle

Tags: datatables

jquery dataTable 1.10+

```
var resourceTable = $("#testTable").DataTable({});
resourceTable.search('searchKey').draw();
```

search is good but when I want to clear, seems no API support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use empty string to clear the search box as shown below:

```
resourceTable.search('').draw();
```

See [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API method for more information.

Comment: thanks for your post, I use the same solution exactly as you do